# Postgres array_agg each value at new string within one row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have such a query

```
SELECT group_id, array_agg(element_id) FROM table
GROUP BY group_id;
```

As a result I have something like that:

```
    group_id | array_agg

    106      | {2147,2138,2144}
    107      | {2132,2510,2139}
```

What query should be written, so result may be depicted in this way:

```
        group_id | array_agg

        106      | {2147
                 |  2138
                 |  2144}
        107      | {2132
                 | 2510
                 | 2139}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically one should format the output in a client app, however you can use `string_agg()` with a new-line character:

```
select group_id, string_agg(element_id::text, e'\n') 
from my_table
group by group_id;

 group_id | string_agg 
----------+------------
      106 | 2147      +
          | 2138      +
          | 2144
      107 | 2132      +
          | 2510      +
          | 2139
(2 rows)
```